# How to achieve smooth sound fading effects?

Tags: c++, audio, effect, sfml, fading

What is the best possible way to smoothly fade in/out a sound with SFML 1.6?

It has `SetVolume()` and `SetAttenuation()`. These two directly set these values. But I need a smooth transition from one sound to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way would be to set the volume lower and lower with each frame/time step.